# NSCollectionView not responding to Mouse/touch events

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am quite new to **MacOS** development but am an experiences iOS developer.

I have a **NSCollectionView** I have got hooked up to a **NSCollectionViewFlowLayout** for horizontal scrolling, I have added lots of cells to it and it works, well almost, it only works with the magic mouse swipe scroll, it ignores all mouse hit events so i can't scroll it with the mouse. I can add a button to a cell and that does detect click actions.

Am stumped its like on iOS the **userInteractionEnabled** has been set to false or something.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var slidesCollection: NSCollectionView!
  var slide : [String] = ["one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two","one", "two"]
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let flowLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
    flowLayout.sectionInset = NSEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    slidesCollection.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
    slidesCollection.dataSource = self
    
    let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: Cell.name, bundle: nil)!
    slidesCollection.register(nib, forItemWithIdentifier: Cell.identifier())
  }
}

extension ViewController: NSCollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return slide.count
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
    let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: Cell.identifier(), for: indexPath)
    
    return item
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and I don't see any issues. Have you tried switching the layout to vertical? How did you test mouse hit events? Is an item view catching the scroll events?

Comment: Am testing by the fact I can't drag the collection view to show the all the cells to the right with the mouse pointer, only the magic mouse swipe. Also I noticed the item selected event doesn't get triggered but that could be something else. Cell is super simple it only has that label which i dont even hook up

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems that this is normal, I just noticed other MacOS apps doing the same with Magic mouse! Think will go back back to iOS development, last time i did desktop app dev was Windows nearly 20 years ago. !